# Add Nginx config file and generate let's encrypt using php

Tags: php, nginx, lets-encrypt

I'm offering a website building service to my clients, where clients can also use their own domain name. On my server, I use Nginx, with the certificates from Let's Encrypt.

Is there any way to create a new Nginx site configuration file using php, or something? Also, is it possible to install a let's encrypt certificate on the new added file?

I hope this is possible, because I want the domain mapping process to be automatic. I already have the things I need, except the Nginx & Let's Encrypt things.

If someone doesn't understand me, here's an example:

> 1. Someone fills in my form from his/her account. (I already have a form)
> 2. My (php) code creates a new Nginx config file with his/her domain in it.
> 3. My (php) code then generates & installs a new Let's Encrypt certificate into the new configuration.
> 4. Finally, the (php) code enables the Nginx configuration. (With a symlink from sites-available to sites-enabled)

If anyone has some codes or tips for me, I appreciate your reply/answer.

Answer (score 0):

From security perspective you shouldn't do such things from the Frontend. That can cause a lot of trouble and you need higher privileges to do that. If you have a Failover structure you have to do that on all nodes which is a bit complicated.

So perhaps you can automate it with Ansible. For Ansible you have a lot of modules. One of them is the Certbot module for Let's Encrypt.

https://github.com/geerlingguy/ansible-role-certbot

In your case you could build a file with all domains, you need, with directory informations and you can run your Ansible role and everything is added for you and your server reloads.

https://github.com/geerlingguy/ansible-role-nginx